# Как устроить ловушку для хакера, или достойно отбивать атаки?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, безопасность, symfony

Ребята выручайте. Меня взломали и в наглую соединились со мной, требуя денег. Я новичок в этом деле и думаю, что пока научусь, то офис скорее снимет меня с работы.

Недавно сайт стал зависать, похоже было на DDOS атаку. Забанил его по IP, но бесполезно. Я устал бегать за IP и банить их, да и в принципе это не выход. Просто когда с хакером переписывался, он сделал ряд проколов, сказав, что может сломать даже мою базу данных. Я когда проверял базу во время перегрузок, то на нее никаких нагрузок не было, в основном на сервер. Меняю всякий раз все возможные пароли, но хакер  беспрепятственно обходит их.

И так, шаря, да выискивая слабые места, наткнулся на то, что мой сервер выдает страницы не только по `index.php`, но и по `abc.php, xyz.php`. Не знаю, блин, но носом чую, что гад припрятал какой-то файл и обращается к нему. Где и идут тормоза, заполняя канал на 100%. Базу удалить, в принципе, можно будет изнутри этого файла (`DELTE FROM tbl_name`).

Как можно найти этот файл, или как можно понять какой-то необычный вход на сервер? У меня Symfony 1.4 PHP фреймворк. Сайт 5 летней давности. Писать его заново? (не вариант, по крайней мере не сейчас). Что я пропустил на уровне хранения лишнего файла? Или не в ту сторону копаю?

Я слышал от друзей что в 90 % за этим стоят конкуренты. И в обратку хакнув его, чаще всего ддос прекращается. Но мысль навредить кому-то из за своей слабости чего-то не вдохновляет.

Попросил хакера дать время, чтоб якобы уболтать начальство расскошелиться.

Comment: Если проблемы выражены только высокой нагрузкой, то скорее всего хакер внутрь не попал. Иначе бы он мог сделать все что угодно, заменить страницу на свою, например. Смотрите по логам web-сервера все обращения. Исключите стандартные обращения к тому же index.php и посмотрите то что останется. Если же все таки выявятся лишние файлы, то тогда надо будет пересмотреть вообще все в системе, потому что могут быть закладки для входа хоть в том же index. смотрите все непонятные места, чаще всего код хакеров обфусцирован, его сразу глазами можно отличить от нормального.

Comment: особое внимание уделите вызовам функции `eval`. в нормальном коде она редко используется, а вот в качестве закладок, что бы выполнять произвольный код. без нее никак. В зависимости от того нашли или нет надо окончательно понять, взлом это или ddos. против ddos могут помочь только фильтры трафика, самодельные или с привлечением сторонних компаний, чистильщиков трафика

Comment: @Mike Блин все так трудно ` Cloudflare` слышал про него.Спасибо всем огромное  Буду завтра готовится к столкновению с монстром,а может и другом  :)

Comment: Буду рад и другим ответам

Comment: И да, правильно пишут в ответе, первым делом сделать бекап всего. потому что если хакер внутри и вы начнете закрывать входы и закроете не все, он может обидеться и что нибудь удалить. И лучше, если подозрительные места есть, внимательно найти все и потом одновременно закрыть все. И еще загляните на http://exploit-db.com посмотрите нет ли чего там на текущие версии используемого софта

Comment: @Mike Ого классно щас буду смотреть.огромное спасибо .у меня возникла шальная мысль,я знаю нашего конкурента.Друзья советуют хакнуть его и ддос прекратится :) Но что мысль напакостить кому то не вдохновляет

Comment: @Sergey простите, но хак конкурента - это глупость. к тому же еще и противозаконная.

Comment: Если писали код сами, то с помощью `git diff` (у вас же сохранился репозиторий проекта, правильно?) сразу будет видно, чего меняли.

Comment: @0andriy в идеальной ситуации конечно можно передеплоить сайт, а ещё лучше пересоздать ВМ, на которой он крутится. Но я что-то сильно сомневаюсь, что тут хотя бы система контроля версий использовалась, не то что девопс какой-то.

Comment: @0andriy Нет не я писал.Сайт 5 летней давности.Вот почему  написан на symfony 1.4 ,Менять боятся. помнить всех деталей чтоб написать тз  :).А GIT не помогает потому что есть много папок в не его.Это я недавно добавил и их в него.

Comment: С помощью обычного WinDiff можно понять где и что было изменено.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

> В принципе не важно вас взломали,или пытаются взломать,ведь рано или поздно мы сталкнёмся с этой угрозой.
>
> Всe действия описанные ниже помогут **узнать о ваших слабых и уязвимых местах**, помогут **исправить допущенные ошибки**, помогут вам **грамотно защищаться** и в дальнейшем **эффективно бороться** с этим злом. Научимся методике и технологиям устраивании ловушек для злоумышленников (**Honeypot - горшочек с медом**).

**Приведу действия первой необходимости:**

**Если вас уже взломали:**

- Меняем логины и пароли серверов (Linux, MySQL, .....).
- Убеждаемся что у нас как минимум две группы пользователей с разными привилегиями.Допустим `web` и `root`, где `web` эта привилегия стоит для всех пользователей с ограниченными возможностями(Запрет на закачку файлов кроме `image type`). Как правильно дать привилегии ? Читаем [**Как Повысить безопасность и удобство использования Вашего сервера и заложить прочную основу для последующих действий.**](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/c-ubuntu-14-04-ru).
- **Если GIT** не показывает необыкновенные изменения,то может быть стоит заглянуть в те директории которые вне него.Чаще всего это те директории куда загружаются изображения или иные файлы которые позволяем пользователям загружать.
- `find . -type f -name '*.php' | xargs grep -l "eval *(str_rot13 *(base64_decode *(" --color` Эта команда найдет php файлы содержащие `eval(str_rot13(base64_decode(` (Также можно искать и в базе данных `SELCT col_nam FROM tbl_name WHERE col_name LIKE '%eval(str_rot13(base64_decode(%'`).
  Синтаксис grep очень прост и вы можете изменить его под свои нужды.

**На уровне PHP:**

1. [**Ограничивать использование опасных php функций в php.ini **](http://php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions)
   (`disable_functions = "show_source, system, shell_exec, exec, eval`"
   ).Можно закрыть `mail()` функцию.и зафиксировать обращение к `SMTP` через сокетное соединение на 25 порт.
2. Тут обращу внимание на функцию `eval`. Если каким то образом в вашем коде припрятан PHP код то его исполнение через `eval` не произойдет.Этот список можно дополнять или убавлять по необходимости.Все отключили любые PHP скрипты которые были написаны надеюсь не нами.
3. [**Межсайтовая подделка запроса**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0) (**CSRF (англ. Сross Site Request Forgery )**):
4. - Много популярных фреймворков имеют полноценную защиту от него в   том числе и ваш.Распространённым способом защиты является механизм, когда с каждой сессией пользователя ассоциируется дополнительный секретный ключ,и при отправки  запроса  в месте с параметрами и отправляется сгенерированный токен.А потом сравниваются сгенерированный токен и токен пришедший с запросом,если совпадают то этот запрос неподделанный. Эффективен для выполнения `POST, PUT, DELETE, STORE`-запросов.
5. **[Межсайтовый скриптинг XSS (англ. Cross-Site Scripting)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3)**. Выводить текст сохраненной не вами на страницу так как  его вводили.Тут есть нюансы.
6. - Если пользователь сохраняет текст (К примеру оставляет комментарий, или делает поиск по сайту) у вас в базе или еще где нибудь, то надо учесть что если нужен только текст тогда до сохранения очистить его от нежелательных тeгов([Для PHP strip_tags — Удаляет `HTML` и PHP-теги из строки](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags.php)).
7. - Если все таки нужно пропускать теги то сделать какие нибудь предварительные валидации.Или вводить их маркируя по принципу `stackoverflow textarea`.Мы же публикуя вопрос или ответ не можем же вводить любой тег.Просто забыл как называется такие типы маркировки текста :)
8. - Всегда тщательно проверяйте файлы которые загружаются на сервер через форму или каким нибудь способом.Проверяйте их расширения и содержимое.Часто загрузка файлов без обеспечения надлежащего контроля безопасности приводит к образованию уязвимостей, которые, как показывает практика, стали настоящей проблемой в веб-приложениях на PHP.**Чтобы удостовериться, что это действительно изображение** не используйте [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.getimagesize.php) для проверки того, что файл является файлом с изображением. Для этих целей используйте расширение **[Fileinfo](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.fileinfo.php)**. Стоит добавить, что желательно **сделать приведение файла к конкретному формату**, например `png`. При приведении метаданные картинки потеряются, обеспечив практически гарантируемую безопастность.Наличие в загрузке файлов с расширением типа `.php` нужно проверять вообще в начале работы сайта, и если они есть сразу же их отбрасывать.

**На уровне .htaccess**

9. **Ограничивать точки входа на сайте**.

   - Например в фреймворках в основном доступ идет через `index.php`.Или других вами известных файлах (`admin.php,back.php, ...`). Всегда можно отследить обращение к другому файлу, и всегда можно логировать информацию об обращениях к подозрительному файлу в отдельном журнале.
   - проверьте `.htaccess` файлы на подозрительные изменения.`auto_append_file` и `auto_prepend_file` включают другие PHP файлы в начале или в конце всех PHP скриптов, злоумышленники могут использовать их для включения своего кода.
     `find . -type f -name '\.htaccess' | xargs grep -i auto_prepend_file;`
   - Следующая команда ищет во всех подкаталогах файлы `.htacсess`, которые содержат '`http`'. Результатом поиска будет список всех правил перенаправлений, в которых могут быть и вредоносные правила `find . -type f -name '\.htaccess' | xargs grep -i http;` .
   - Во все каталоги, доступные для записи добавляем файл `.htaccess` со следующим содержимым:

     `php_flag engine 0`

     `RemoveHandler .phtml .php .php2 .php3 .php4 .php5 .php7 .phps .cgi .pl .asp .aspx .shtml .shtm .fcgi .fpl .htm .html`

     `AddType text/plain .phtml .php .php2 .php3 .php4 .php5 .php6 .php7 .phps .cgi .pl .asp .aspx .shtml .shtm .fcgi .fpl .htm .html`

Этим самым мы отключаем PHP в данном каталоге и заставляем все скрипты отображаться как HTML.
Это можно сделать просто на всякий случай. Лишним уж точно не будет.

Или запрет на исполнение:

```
<FilesMatch ".(php|asp|fcgi| ...) $">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

**На уровне баз данных,частностью MySQL:**

- Всегда пользуйтесь **[Подготовленными запросами и хранимыми процедурами:](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php)**
- Большинство баз данных поддерживают концепцию подготовленных запросов. Что это такое? Это можно описать, как некий вид скомпилированного шаблона SQL запроса, который будет запускаться приложением и настраиваться с помощью входных параметров. У подготовленных запросов есть два главных преимущества:

  - Запрос необходимо однажды подготовить и затем его можно запускать столько раз, сколько нужно, причем как с теми же, так и с отличающимися параметрами.
  - Параметры подготовленного запроса не требуется экранировать кавычками; драйвер это делает автоматически. Если в приложении используются исключительно подготовленные запросы, разработчик может быть уверен, что никаких SQL инъекций случиться не может (однако, если другие части текста запроса записаны с неэкранированными символами, SQL-инъекции все же возможны; здесь речь идет именно о параметрах).
- [**Защищайтесь от SQL-инъекции**](http://php.net/manual/ru/security.database.sql-injection.php)

  - Прямое внедрение вредоносных инструкций в SQL-запросы - это методика, в которой взломщик создает или изменяет текущие SQL-запросы для отображения скрытых данных, их изменения или даже выполнения опасных команд операционной системы на сервере базы данных. Атака выполняется на базе приложения, строящего SQL-запросы из пользовательского ввода и статических параметров.

**На уровне системы Linux ...**

- Лучше этих сервисов, которые реально защищают от DDOS, я пока не знаю.Пользуюсь ими.Пока что отбивают :).Это [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/)
  ,и [Incapsula](https://www.incapsula.com/)

### Как устроить ловушку для хакера  (Honeypot - горшочек с медом):

*Не занимайтесь этим если  у вас нет достаточных
знаний и квалификации, хакер может победить
вас в вашей же ловушке.*

Honeypot (горшочек с медом) давно широко
используется в мире компьютерной безопасности.Это ресурс, задача которого отдаться хакеру, цель которого принять тест, атаку и быть взломанным.

Это может быть эмулятор другой системы или приложения, некая "темница с засадой", или просто стандартная система. Как бы вы не построили свой горшочек, главная его задача — подвергнутся нападению и рассказать вам в подробностях об этом.

- **[Quick and Simple PHP Honey Pot Spam Prevention](http://devgrow.com/simple-php-honey-pot/)**
- **[Simple PHP HoneyPot Tutorial](http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/php/simple-php-honeypot.php)**
- **[Изучить инструменты, тактику и мотивы, связанные с компьютерными и сетевыми атаками, и поделиться извлеченными уроками.](http://www.honeynet.org/)**

Естественно все в этом посте перечислить невозможно.Но если попытаться реализовать все что в этом посте перечислено,то можно научиться защищаться и не хило.По каждому из пунктов можно всегда задать вопрос или поискать больше информации для более детальной и правильной ее реализации.

**Полезные материалы :**

- **Веб-сервисы для проверки сайтов на вирусы https://habrahabr.ru/post/303956/**
- Методы борьбы с DDoS-атаками https://habrahabr.ru/post/129181/
- 5 советов по борьбе с DDOS-атаками http://www.securitylab.ru/analytics/442099.php
- Устоять любой ценой: методы борьбы с DoS/DDoS-атаками https://xakep.ru/2009/10/14/49752/
- 5 программ для анализа безопасности Вашего сайта https://seo-zona.ru/5-programm-dlya-analiza-bezopasnosti-vashego-sajta-2015-03-31.html
- Как понять что ваш сайт был взломан https://www.siteguarding.com/ru/kak-poniat-chto-vash-sait-byl-vzloman

**Бесплатный онлайн-сканеры вирусов:**

- **Веб-сканер QUTTERA https://quttera.com/**
- **Веб-сканер ReScan.pro https://rescan.pro/**
- **VirusTotal https://www.virustotal.com/ru/**
- **Веб-сканер Sucuri https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/**
- **Онлайн—сканеры Dr.Web https://vms.drweb.ru/online/**

***Вооружайтесь знаниями. Будьте бдительней.***.

Удачи :)

Comment: Я про «Нe бойтесь хакеров.». Их как раз стоит бояться и защищаться от них.

Comment: @Alex78191 Я в принципе догадался что вы имели в виду :). Естественно надо защищаться от них и весь пост посвящен именно этому.

Comment: @AVM не стоит выделять названия и аббревиатуры, вроде Linux и PHP как код: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328/

Comment: Добавлю. Следует выключить исполнение PHP-файлов в папках, куда пользователь может загружать файлы. Это будет дополнительным слоем защиты.

Comment: И еще стоит выключить include через url на всякий случай

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov "Следует выключить исполнение PHP-файлов в папках". 9.Ограничивать точки входа на сайте. тут говорится об этом.

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan там говорится про логирование обращений к другим файлам, я же говорю про закрытие доступа

Answer (score 16):

Как минимум сделай это

- Сделай бэкапы всего
- Ищи в проекте новые файлы по дате
- Проверь где-то свои исходники, мб по уже существующей сигнатуре вируса найдет что-то.
- И самое главное, не понятно по какой причине вы еще используете Symfony 1.4.
- Я думаю возможно есть баг в этой версии или у вашем коде.
- Посмотрите места там где у вас загружаются файлы.
- Поставьте модуль для Nginx (если он стоит, если нету, ставьте) модуль для анти ддоса. Вот статья https://habrahabr.ru/post/139931/
- Соглашусь с комментариями, поищите в проекте `grep`'ом `eval`

Answer (score 11):

Заранее извините за советы на уровне КО. Однако...

Обратите внимание на специфику вашего проекта. Если ваши клиенты из России, обрубите все иностранные ip. Очень вероятно, что злоумышленник ходит к вам через зарубежный прокси.

Предлагаю разместить на главной форму интересную для злоумышленника, но не интересную для клиентов. Например, вход для дилеров/оптовиков/партнеров. Скорее всего злоумышленник попытается атаковать новую форму, засветив свой ip.

Оцените вероятность внутренней угрозы. Возможно ли, что это кто-то из сотрудников организации?

Попробуйте публичные сканеры безопасности, типа таких https://observatory.mozilla.org/
Конечно эти сервисы достаточно параноидальны и не все нужно внедрять на рабочих проектах. Но может быть вам удастся закрыть какие-либо дыры.

И на мой взгляд хорошо бы поставить в известность руководство. Возможно это поможет найти средства на платный аудит безопасности.

Comment: Ну а если через прокси то что делать ,как ему запрещать это ?

Comment: российские прокси пройдут. но скорее всего это будут зарубежные прокси. еще мысль разместить фейковую форму на главной. по атакам на нее отслеживать ip.

Comment: Пользователи же будут видеть эту форму ?Или какой то хитрый ход есть что можно зделать ? Оформьте пожалуста как ответ описывая ваши действия .Это тоже очень полезно

Comment: @Sergey, пользователь увидел форму "вход для партнёров" - но он не партнёр и её (почти) не тронет. А хакер попробует взломать, потому что ему не важно, партнёр он или нет :)

Comment: @Qwertiy Глупый хакер который читает журнал хакер может и клюнет.А этот нет.Видать титулованный :)